# how to take into account the presence of more than one space? java

Tags: java, eclipse

**Task:** There is a string. Calculate the number of words in the string. The word is considered separated by spaces. (*You can not use regular expressions*)

**How to solve?** If you enter two or more spaces in a row - will consider that these words but I need to count as one big pass between the words

**Example** I_live_in_Lviv - 4 words, but if we put one more space (for an example before Lviv) -> I_live_in__Lviv - 5 words (instead of underlining, put a space(-s))

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();

int n = 0;

if (line.length() != 0) {
    n++;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (line.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            n++;
        }
     }
}
System.out.print(n);
```

**Answer:**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();

int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length() - 1; i++){
    if(Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))){
        count++;
        for( ; i <= line.length() - 1; i++){
            if(line.charAt(i) == ' '){
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
System.out.print(count);

in.close();
```

*Result:*

I_live_in__Lviv_    - 4

Comment: Let's take an example: `abc    def   ghi`. There are 3 words, right? What are the characters that start a new word? a, d and g, right? What do they have in common? They're all non-space characters, preceded by a space character, or by no character at all, right? So, start from there to implement your logic.

Comment: Why would it? Explain.

Comment: @ JB Nizet but if you put 2 spaces before 'def ' or other word -> abc def ghi. It will count 4 words, not 3 – words

Comment: Is 'a' a non-space char preceded by a space char or by nothing? yes. Count = 1. Is 'b' a non-space char preceded by a space char or by nothing? No. count = 1. Is 'c' a non-space char preceded by a space char or by nothing? No. count = 1. is ' ' a non-space character ...? No. count = 1. Is ' ' a non-space character...? No. count = 1. Is 'd' a non-space character preceded by a space char or by nothing? Yes. count = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I'm understanding you have a string, e.g. " hi my  name is       Matthew" and you want to find how many words are in the string. I would just take two characters at a time, but step them by one, and test if the first is a space and the second isn't. So take " h", that's the beginning of a word. Then "hi", that's not, etc. Of course you'd want to check if the first character isn't a space and if not increment the word count.

Edit: Sorry I didn't elaborate, I was in a time crunch this morning. Use `String.subString(i, i + 2);` to get two characters from the string. Then check the new string with either subString() or charAt() (I'd recommend charAt()), of course accounting for the string length - 2 to prevent an error being thrown.

```
for (int i = 0; i < exampleString.length - 2; i++) {
//subtract 2 to prevent subString from throwing an error
    if ((exampleString.subString(i, i + 2).charAt(1) = " " && exampleString.subString(i, i + 2).charAt(2) != " ") || i = 0) {
//add 2 to get a space and a letter, then test the first character for a 
//space and the second character for NOT a space, also increment words if 
//i = 0, presuming there is no space at the beginning of the string
        words++;
    }
}
```

So basically what @JB Nizet said, only in answer form... sorry I didn't see your comment until now, I wouldn't have typed all of this

Comment: @ MattJew thank you but how to do without the method - subString. I mean, do not use standard java methods

Comment: Ooh that's what you meant by that okay... That's slightly more complicated

Comment: So according to your example 5 words are calculated when there are 4 spaces?

Comment: @ MattJew yes, so I ask how to account for spaces if they are more than one, that is, 2 or more? and counted as one continuous space -> I_live___in_Lviv - 4 -> result must be 4 words, not 6 words (there are 5 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

just add one more variable and store the previous character in it. Check if it is space with the next character if it returns false increment the count.

Comment: @ Shashank Lipate  in general i don't understand how your method can help can you explain more ? I will be grateful !)

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = in.nextLine();

    int n = 0;
char a=' ';
    if (line.length() != 0) {
        n++;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == ' ' && a !=' ') {
                n++;
            }a=line.charAt(i);
         }
    }
    System.out.print(n);

Comment: @ Shashank Lipate but there is another problem if we put 1 or more than 1 spaces in the end of our sting (I_live___in_Lviv_ or I_live___in_Lviv__________ ... )  it will count - 5. So can you help me to fix or explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();

int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length() - 1; i++){
    if(Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))){
        count++;
        for( ; i <= line.length() - 1; i++){
            if(line.charAt(i) == ' '){
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
System.out.print(count); //I_live_in__Lviv_ - 4

in.close();
```